# Why does this recursive function output multiple results/possibilities? This is part of the code for a sudoku puzzle solver

Tags: python

This is a sudoku solver. Why does it output all the possibilities in a given sudoku puzzles and not just one? After the input “More?”, the puzzle will output another result. Why?

```
def solve():
  global board
  global score
  for x in range(0,9):
    for y in range(0,9):
      if board[x][y] == 0:
        for z in range(1,10):
          if possible(y, x, z):
            board[x][y] = z
            solve()
         
            board[x][y] = 0
        return
       
  print_grid()
  input("More?")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `input("More?")` does not play any role in the flow of your program.

You can checkout the documentation for input function here https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input. But basically `input` function does 3 things:

1. Print the prompt "More?"
2. Wait for user input
3. Return user input as string

Maybe, you can rewrite the last line like below:

```
if input("More?") == "N":
    return
```

Edit: To address your question: How can the function print out all possible solutions?

I assume x = 0 at the left-most cell, x = 9 at right-most cells. y = 0 at top cell and y = 9 at bottom cell.

- The first loop is translated to scanning each column left to right
- The second loop is translated to scanning each cell in a column from top to bottom
- In each cell:

  - If cell value is not set, check all possible values for the cell

    > Try each possible value iteratively and call `solve()` again **(1)**. The call to `solve` can either success, print board or fail and print nothing. In either case, the temporary value is cleared to try new value.

    > If no possible value found => terminate **(2)**
  - If cell value is set => ignore and continue with new cell
- Finally, each call to `solve` may success and print the board or terminate at **(2)**

Notice that after each call to `solve` at **(1)**, cell value is always reset

==> Basically, the "original" `solve` function loop over all empty cells try each possible value while other cells unchanged. Then it clone itself, send the clone back to the start of the table to fill other empty cells. The clone now see the table with 1 less empty cells compared to the original. The clone now again fill 1 empty cell, clone itself and send the clone of clone back to the start of table. The clone of clone now see the table with 2 less empty cells compared to the original.

If you continue with this line of thought, you can see the algorithm here try every possible values (i.e brute-force) ==> No wonder that it can print out all solutions.

Comment: I know what the input function does. It’s only roll in this function is to temporarily pause the program so that the user can choose whether or not they want another solution to the puzzle if there is one. My question is as follows. What makes this program capable of finding multiple solutions to one puzzle? How does recursion play a role in this program?

Comment: @user14452429: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I edited my answer, you can check it out.

Comment: @user14452429 : If you think your question is satisfactorily answered. You can give an upvote and accept the answer. Thanks